# Where to find "Up Next" on tv.apple.com?

Tags: web-browser, appletv

I have a MacBook running High Sierra, so I don't have the Apple TV application. I use a web browser (Google Chrome in particular, but it doesn't seem to matter) to watch the shows on tv.apple.com.

But it's inconvenient having to scroll through all the shows to find the one I want to watch. I added the show to "Up Next", but I can't seem to find that on the web page. Am I missing something, or is that feature only available when using the app or an Apple TV device?